# How to split a polygon with rings?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, splitting

The issue I am experencing is that I have an advanced polygon (*buffered lines that were then merged into a multipolygon and then split into single parts*) that I can not use the split tool on.

In the polygon below, when I attempt to use the 'split into multiple features' tool it does not perform any splitting action.  'Split Parts' tool also does seem to work on this polygon as well.

The end goal is to have each line separated - ideally each as their own polygon.

[image: Multipart Polygon]
Current State

[image: Goal]
Desired polygon splits

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Make sure that when you use the splitting tool, the split line starts and ends outside the polygon. It won't work if you start or end inside a ring. 2) Use the Geometry Checker plugin to make sure the polygon has valid geometry.

Comment: Performing a split through both sides of the polygon solved the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that when you use the splitting tool, the split line starts and ends outside the polygon. It won't work if you start or end inside a ring

[image]